# Codeigniter HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) when upload code to server

Tags: php, codeigniter

On localhost, website run normal.
But when i upload to hosting => it's return HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Same result if i call unavailable library or call unavailable function on library (it don't return any error, just blank page)

Example:

```
class My_Email extends CI_Email{
    public function sz_send($to,$bcc,$subject,$content)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        // get config
        $CI->load->model('config_model');
        $site_config = $CI->config_model->getconfig();
        // init mail

        $mail_config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $mail_config['smtp_host'] = $site_config['mail_host'];
        $mail_config['smtp_port'] = $site_config['mail_port'];
        $mail_config['smtp_user'] = $site_config['mail_user'];
        $mail_config['smtp_pass'] = $site_config['mail_pass'];
        $mail_config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $mail_config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $mail_config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $mail_config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';
        $mail_config['newline']    = "\r\n";
        $mail_config['validation'] = TRUE;
        $CI->load->library('email');
        $CI->email->initialize($mail_config);
        $CI->email->from($site_config['mail_user'], $site_config['mail_name']);
        $CI->email->to($to);
        $CI->email->bcc($bcc);
        $CI->email->subject($subject);
        $CI->email->message($content);
        if($CI->email->send()){
            return TRUE; 
        } else {
            //echo $CI->email->print_debugger();
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

And in controller, i call:

```
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->sz_send($user->email,'','Subject',$mailcontent);
```

Website return with a blank page with FF and  HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) with Chorme

p/s: how can i see apache log file on hosting (linux)?

Comment: hello! i have also have a same problem but i found that i could not upload the .htaccess file that remove the index.php . after upload this my site work as normal as my localhost  . **Are you upload the htaccess file** ???

Comment: @Hameed: Please create a new question with your specific information.

Comment: @MikePurcell :) dude its not my question . i just asking him that can he upload .htaccess file or not. ?

Comment: @Hameed: yes, i have .htaccess to remove index.php in url.